# Managing membership provider on web service the right way

Tags: c#, wcf, sqlanywhere

I have a Silverlight 5 app and a WCF service that stores/gets from membership api some information related to users with the Sybase Anywhere provider.

Piece of `web.config`:

```
...
<profile defaultProvider="SAProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SAProfileProvider" type="iAnywhere.Web.Security.SAProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MyContext" applicationName="/" commandTimeout="30" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add type="System.String" name="MyUserData" />
...
```

The service returns the data stored in MyUserData

```
public string GetMyUserData()
    {
        try
        {
            string result = null;
            result = HttpContext.Current.Profile.GetPropertyValue("MyUserData") as string;
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = string.Empty;
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.ErrorException(e.Message, e);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

but sometimes I get an error:

> Invalid request on pooled connection iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.SAException (0x80004005): Run time SQL error -- *** ERROR *** Assertion failed: 104909 (12.0.1.3967)

Can I replace my catch like this?

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    _logger.ErrorException(e.Message, e);
}
```